# NoClassDefFoundError Proguard Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, proguard

I'm using Proguard to obfuscate my Android app. 
Everything works perfectly except for one `Activity`.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.myapp.android.MediaActivity
```

When I don't use Proguard the `Activity` is working fine. I only have this issue when using Proguard.

My `Activity` is declared on the `AndroidManifest` and all my others `Activity` are working fine, I only have the issue on this particular one.

Here is my Proguard config :

```
-dontpreverify
-repackageclasses ''
-allowaccessmodification
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic
-keepattributes *Annotation*

-keep class com.myapp.android.MediaActivity { *; }

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider

-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
    public void set*(...);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    static android.os.Parcelable$Creator CREATOR;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

-keepclassmembers class * {
    @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface <methods>;
}

# Also keep - Enumerations. Keep the special static
# methods that are required in enumeration classes.
-keepclassmembers enum  * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

# We want to keep methods in Activity that could be used in the XML attribute onClick
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}


# keep setters in Views so that animations can still work.
# see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#beans
-keepclassmembers public class * extends android.view.View {
   void set*(***);
   *** get*();
}

# We want to keep methods in Activity that could be used in the XML attribute onClick
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

# For enumeration classes, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#enumerations
-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}
```

As you can see I've also add this specific line to try to make it work, but it's not :

```
-keep class com.myapp.android.MediaActivity { *; }
```

**EDIT :**
Here are the imports of the MediaActivity :

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.myapp.android.fragment.places.FragmentSupportPlacesBase;
import com.myapp.android.fragment.grid.BaseCursorGridFragmentSupport;
import com.myapp.android.fragment.grid.SupportScreenShotCursorGridFragment;
import com.myapp.android.fragment.grid.SupportTimelineCursorGridFragment;
import com.myapp.android.model.Place;
import com.myapp.android.model.SelectedInfo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
```

Does anyone as any ideas why it's occurring and how can I fix that ?

Comment: Can you post the imports of `MediaActivity`? Maybe the problem is that Proguard is obfuscating some of those classes

Comment: I have added the import in the question. Maybe you are right but a lot of my Activities are using those type of imports. Fragments, model Objects, Toolbar, pretty basic stuff ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks antonio for pointing me in the right direction.
My `Activity` was implementing an Interface `PlacesCallbacks` (for no reason)

```
public interface PlacesCallbacks{
    void onPlaceSelected(long quadKey, short zoomLevel);
    void onPlaceSelected(Place place);
}
```

However this `Interface` wasn't used in this `Activity`, and neither anywhere in my app, and the method implemented were left empty.

So I guess Proguard remove this `Interface` because it's wasn't used anywhere, but it was implemented in my `Activity`.

All I had to do is deleting the `Interface`.

Comment: interesting - are you saying it removed the Activity just because it contained an unused `interface`?

Comment: I don't think it removed the Activity, but the Interface because it wasn't really used anywhere even though it was implemented in this Activity. And I think it crash because it couldn't find the Interface in this Activity afterwards. I'm not 100% sure that it's what happen though, just a theory.

Comment: Doesn't make sense to me because the error says the Activity can't be found. Interesting quirk.

Comment: Maybe, so it means that it would be bigger bug in Proguard, it would remove classes who implements unused interface ?